# Java Unsorted List Array

Tags: java, arrays, list

Im working on a project, and the below methods are not working properly.
It supposed to create a random list of numbers, and then the methods on the list should work like this:
find (finds the value)
delete (deletes the value) Should call find in order to get the actual number's location
delete all (deletes all the numbers n from the list)
finds all (same number on different array locations)

Delete for example deletes the fit item in the list when the number I'm looking for is not contained in the list. Find should be called from delete I have not idea how to implement delete all / find all

```
package bp;


public class UnsortedList implements IUnsortedList {

    public final int MAX_SIZE = 10000;
    public final int MAX_VALUE = 10;
    private int sizeOfList = 0;
    private boolean duplicatesAllowed = true;
    private final int[] listItems = new int[MAX_SIZE];
    int searchKey;
    int f;
    int n;


    @Override
    public int getSizeOfList() {
        return sizeOfList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areDuplicatesAllowed() {
        return duplicatesAllowed;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDupliatesAllowed(boolean pDuplicatesAllowed) {
        duplicatesAllowed = pDuplicatesAllowed;

    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        sizeOfList = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void insert(int pValueToInsert) {
        //PLace the value in the last index position and increase the size of list
        if (sizeOfList < MAX_SIZE) {
            listItems[sizeOfList++] = pValueToInsert;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int pValueToDelete) {
        int positionToDelete = find(pValueToDelete);
        searchKey = pValueToDelete;
        for ( f = 0; f < sizeOfList; f++)
            if(listItems[f] == searchKey)
                break;
        for (int k = f; k < sizeOfList-1; k++)
            listItems[k] = listItems[k+1];
        sizeOfList--;

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll(int pValueToDelete) {

    }

    @Override
    public void initializeWithRandomData(int pSizeOfList) {

        if(duplicatesAllowed) {
            for (int n=0; n < pSizeOfList; ++n) {
                listItems[n] = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_VALUE +1);
                ++sizeOfList;
            }
        } else {
            for (int n= 0; n < pSizeOfList; ++n) {
                int newvalue = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_VALUE +1);
                while (find(newvalue) > -1) {
                    newvalue = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_VALUE +1);
                }

                listItems[n] = newvalue;
                ++sizeOfList;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int find(int pValueToFind) {
        searchKey = pValueToFind;
        for (n=0; n < sizeOfList; n++)
            if (listItems[n] == searchKey)
                break;
            if (n == sizeOfList)
                System.out.println("Can't find " + searchKey);
            else
                System.out.println("Found " + searchKey);

        return 0    ;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] findAll(int pValueToFind) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int n = 0; n < sizeOfList; n++) {
            sb.append(listItems[n]);
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: _the below methods are not working properly_ is not very helpful. Please add details about errors/problems and how to reproduce them.

Comment: Sorry crystal ball not working today, so what is not working?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't back it with an `ArrayList` instead of an array?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `find` method...

A part from the reliance on a class instance variable, which is never initialised before it is used, you return `0` from the method...

```
public int find(int pValueToFind) {
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore the result of calling this method will always be `0`, hence the first element get's deleted...

Instead, first, initialise `n` to `0` so you are always searching the from the start, then return `n` when you are done...

```
public int find(int pValueToFind) {
    searchKey = pValueToFind;
    n = 0;
    //...
    if (n == sizeOfList) {
        n = -1;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: That only fixes the find method

Comment: @user2856759 Well, that got you one step closer. I suggest you to this opportunity to learn how to use the debugger, add a break point at the first line of the delete method and step through the logic. I can tell you that you can simplify the method by taking out the first loop, because you ignoring the result fro. The find method. Remember, we're not your debugging service, you'll have to do some work yourself ;)